# Is docker always using RAM?

Tags: docker

I have PostgreSQL in docker container. My device's used  ram increases when data grows. Is there a way to change it to Hard disk storage from Ram Storage? If it continues like this, it will be very expensive. What is formal storage on docker?

Comment: Of course yes. Running software needs some hardware

Comment: Yes. The question is docker container only using ram. Docker is storing all data on RAM. It makes expensive. How to change it to hard disk storage?

Comment: Buy more RAM. It is the cheapest solution. Your manpower is costly

Comment: I think what are you asking is how you can avoid storing Postgres data in memory. An option would be to use a volume, enabling storing data in hard disk.

Comment: Great Solution.. No need for more than the  answer of the question @BasileStarynkevitch .

Answer (score 2):

There are runtime options `--memory-swap`, `--memory-reservation` and `--memory` to do this. See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#limit-a-containers-access-to-memory)

Answer (score 0):

**Docker images** are built from layers, and each layer is a read-only filesystem. This means that when you create a new image, it is a snapshot of the state of the filesystem at the time the image was built.

Any changes that you make to the filesystem in an image will not be persisted to the image itself.
When you run a container from an image, the *container is created from a read-write copy of the image's filesystem*. This means that any changes that you make to the filesystem in the container will be persisted to the container itself. However, once the container is stopped, the filesystem will be reset to its original state.

This means that ***Docker images are volatile***, meaning that they do not retain any changes made to them after they are created. This is in contrast to persistent storage, which retains data even after the container is stopped or deleted.

### Reference

- [Manage data in Docker](https://docs.docker.com/storage/)

---

### Changing Storage from RAM to Hard Disk

If your concern is increasing RAM usage as the PostgreSQL data grows, you can consider configuring persistent storage for your PostgreSQL data outside the container. Docker volumes allow you to map container directories to host directories, effectively storing data on the host's hard disk instead of in the container's RAM.

You can create a Docker volume for PostgreSQL data like so:

```bash
docker run -v /path/on/host:/var/lib/postgresql/data -e POSTGRES_DB=mydb -e POSTGRES_USER=myuser -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword postgres
```